# EF MySQL ApplicationUser MVC5

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I updated my visual studio with update 4 and using EntityFramework 6.1.1, and since then I'm having problems connecting projects to MySQL.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider) and before everything was working good, but now with the new update I'm getting errors:

The IdentityModel:

```
static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    //public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Settings> Settings { get; set; }
```

Here my [tests](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vihsrso00zyqme/Archive.zip?dl=0) if someone could take a look.

The error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

and

```
Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

on:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
```

My question now is what this mean? and can I fix this?

Comment: Its not a problem with your c# code its the actual mysql query thats the problem.

Comment: After you upgrade VS you should have updated MySql Connector too, IMHO it was not necesary eagerly give up to EF 6.1.2

Comment: the MySql Connector is on latest 6.9.5 and ODBC 5.3.4

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was just me who was having this problem! It starts when you perform the upgrade to the Entity Framework 6.1.2!

The only solution I found for now, was to perform the downgrade to 6.1.1 version of Entity Framework.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly now. I was getting crazy with this, I really wanted to work with the new users

Comment: but now I got the error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. See my edit